# React JS installation stuck

Tags: reactjs

I am a beginner in ReactJS.I am trying to install ReactJs in my windows system.And as per the requirement of npm i have installed in it.Now when i am trying to run the command npx create-react-app  to install the ReactJs then it will be stuck in the middle.So please help me out to fix this issue.Below i have attached screenshot of it where it been stuck.

[image]

**Note : Installing ReactJs through yarn is also stuck at some point.Below i have attached image of it.**

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: your screenshots show actually that it is done. have you checked your repositories ?

Comment: after it says done in xx seconds try pressing enter

Comment: @MohamedELAYADI i have checked repositories there is only 2 files created and a folder of node_modules.

Comment: @AtinSingh it shows like something is in process but it stucks over there.

Comment: Please post text, not images of text.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `create-react-app` on Windows is just taking a really long time to complete. It is creating a git repository and doesn't give any output in this stage. You just have to be patient :)

You can see if it's doing anything by looking at the cpu usage of Node.js in the Task Manager

I've seen a couple people having issues with this, so it must be a global issue with the current release.

Answer (score 0):

Sohil, have you checked to see that you haven't accidentally installed it globally? Sometimes if you use npm and yarn at the same time you'll give your path a tummy ache.  I would run `npm uninstall` and `yarn remove` on both the local and global level and throw in an `npm cache clean` for good measure then run a fresh installation. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: I have again fresh install the yarn and then also installation stucks at some point.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using yarn for node package manager. Then use yarn to install create-react-app.

Use the below commands.

```
yarn create react-app my-app
```